# How many permutations can be made by taking all $6$ items from set $A$ and one of the $12$ items from set $B$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If you have $2$ sets, sets $A$ and $B$. Set $A$ has $6$ distinct items and set $B$ has $12$ distinct items. How many permutations can you make by taking $6$ items from set $A$ and one item from set $B$?

My attempt:

Since I have to take $6$ items from set $A$, their permutations will be $6! = 720$.  One item from Set $B$ containing $12$ items. Hence, its permutations will be $12$.

So total permutations should be $720 \cdot 12 = 8640$.

Comment: Edit your question by adding your effort.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Answer (score 2):

An item can be selected from set B in $\binom{12}{1}=12$ different ways.

Then $6$ items from set A and an item from set B, the total number of items is $7$

the number of permutations is
$12\times 7!$

Comment: One remark: this requires to have $A \cup B$ to have distinct elements only, otherwise the output has duplicates. As I understand, the problem statement doesn't guarantee this.

Comment: @Dávid Laczkó , It says 6 items from set A and set A has only 6 items.

Comment: I mean if any of $B$'s elements has the same value of one of $A$'s.

Comment: @Dávid Laczkó, I see, but in the question it did not mention they may have same items. So they must be different from each other.